# Deserialization with nested polymorphic objects via jakson Java 

Tags: java, json, polymorphism, jackson

I have a container for nested objects like:

```
class A {
  private Type type;// can message or invite 
  private Notification notification;
```

}

and classes

```
abstract class Notification {}

class Message extends Notification {}

class Invite extends Notification {}
```

When I serialize List to JSON all works fine, but I can make deserialization with ObjectMapper because jackson doesn't know the the instance type of Notification, that are stored in *type* field. Question is it possible to deserialize with ObjectMapper?

Comment: Just Curious: Why does the container A have a field for the type of Notification?

Comment: To pass information about type Notifications to the client. Notification object doesn't contain information about it type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I also struggled with this issue but there is a nice blog item here;

http://www.cowtowncoder.com/blog/archives/2010/03/entry_372.html

This should explain everything